# How can I use a model object without inserting it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm using data model in my project and sometimes I need to fetch some data from server without inserting it in database. But I want to manipulate this data using my model. But each time I create a model object it is inserted when managedObjectContext executes the `save` method.

What should I do in this case? Do I need to have a copy of this classes but without data model to manipulate data in a object without inserting it in database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass `nil` to the context argument of NSManagedObject's `initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:` method. This will create an object that is not associated with any context, but will otherwise act as normal (except for `awakeFromInsert` will not be called.

This is mentioned explicitly in the documentation, so it is not a hack:

> If context is not nil, this method invokes [context insertObject:self] (which causes awakeFromInsert to be invoked).

Comment: thanks, but is it not going to produce an exception?

Comment: I don't know, I'm only asking

Comment: Hey your answer work for me and the app doesn't crash for that. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

> But each time I create a model object it is inserted when managedObjectContext execute the save method.

One possibility is to use a separate managed object context for these transient objects. It's often said that a managed object context is like a scratch pad for manipulating your data. It's can be easy to create new contexts for temporary use, but only if you design your code such that it doesn't assume that there's just one context.

This is a great example of how you can easily go wrong with singletons -- many apps use a singleton object (for example, the app delegate) to make it easy to access "the" managed object context. That's conceptually simple, but if your classes fetch the MOC from some singleton, you can't tell them to use a different MOC. If you instead design your classes such that the caller provides the MOC (or whatever objects they need to do their job) it becomes easy to use multiples MOC's.

Comment: In particular, your can use a separate MOC based on an `NSInMemoryStoreType` store instead of the "usual" `NSSQLiteStoreType`.

Comment: Hi thank you for answer. How can I create a new MOC ? is it save for the app?

Comment: Your answer was good but the other one was more simple than this one.